# JVM - customize console output in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, logging, jvm, logback

I've built a `logback` implementation which allows me to sufficiently customize log files. Works great. I'm trying to customize the look of the debug console output in IntelliJ but having a difficult time finding where that format is defined.

I thought creating a `consoleAppender` with a custom pattern would do the trick, but it simply doubles the output (original output first, my custom appender second):

```bash
16:02:20.477 [main] INFO ROOT -- this is an info message
12-20 16:02:20.477 [main] ~~INFO ~~ ROOT -> this is an info message
16:02:20.477 [main] TRACE ROOT -- this is a trace message
12-20 16:02:20.477 [main] ~~TRACE~~ ROOT -> this is a trace message
```

How/where can I customize the standard Debug Console output (without duplicating it)?